# Converting English to First Order Logic

Tags: logic, discrete-optimization

I have a question with a table of FOLs and Predicates and I am given a set of sentences I need to convert from English to FOL. I have posted the image at the bottom of the question.

I am fairly new to this concept of universal quantifiers and I would really appreciate if someone could just take a look and let me know if I am handling these correctly?

**Whenever Thabo drives a lorry in Durban, he is involved in an accident**

∀x ∀y (Drives(thabo, bloemfontein) ⇒ Accident(thabo))

**Kitty is involved in an accident only if she does not obey the traffic rules.**

∃x [(accident(kitty) ⇐⇒ ¬ (Obeys(kitty))]

**Unless Betty obeys the traffic rules when she drives a lorry in Bloemfontein, she is involved in an accident.**

∀x [(obeys(betty) ∧ ∀y(Drives(betty, bloemfontein)) ⇒ accident(betty)]

**Durban or Bloemfontein is a city.**

∀x [City(durban) ∨ city(Bloemfontein)]

**If we assume that Kitty drives a lorry in Durban, either Thabo or Betty drives a lorry in Bloemfontein.**

∀x [Drives(kitty, Durban) ⇒ ∀x ∀y ((Drives(thabo, bloemfontein) ∨ (Drives(betty, bloemfontein))]

**Neither Kitty nor Betty obeys the traffic rules.**

∀x [¬(obeys(kitty) ∨ obeys(betty))]

**Thabo is involved in accident if and only if both he and Betty do not obey the traffic rules.**

∀x [Accident(thabo) ⇐⇒ ¬ (obeys(thabo) ∨ obeys(kitty))]

**None of Thabo, Kitty or Betty is involved in an accident.**

∀x [¬(Accident(thabo) ∧ Accident(kitty) ∧ Accident(betty)]

**If Kitty obeys the traffic rules and Betty does not drive a lorry in Bloemfontein, Thabo is not involved in an accident.**

∃x [(obeys(kitty) ∧ ¬∀x ∀y (Drives(betty, bloemfontein)) ⇒ Accident(thabo))]

**Thabo obeys the traffic rules only if he drives a lorry in Durban.**

∃x [(obeys(thabo) ⇐⇒ (Drives(thabo, durban))]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll point out one thing:

None of Thabo, Kitty or Betty is involved in an accident.

∀x [¬(Accident(thabo) ∧ Accident(kitty) ∧ Accident(betty)]

Why do you have ∀x when x doesn't appear anywhere in your formula? You are not making a generic statement "every person that", your statement only includes three determined people.

Also, what you wrote translates to:

For every person, `It is not the case that Thabo is in an accident and Kitty is in an accident and Betty is in an accident.` because the negation binds the case that all three are simultaneously in an accident.

However, by you translation something like `Thabo is in an accident and Kitty is not in an accident and Betty is not in an accident is valid`.

Makes sense? :)

Update: Second thing I'll point out

Kitty is involved in an accident only if she does not obey the traffic rules.

∃x [(accident(kitty) ⇐⇒ ¬ (Obeys(kitty))]

Are you sure that you can determine that if kitty does not obey the traffic she will be involved in an accident? What the sentence suggests to be is that **if** she is involved in an accident **then** she is not obeying the traffic rules. But, it does not guarantee that not obeying the rules will cause an accident.

Again, unnecessary ∃x statement. You are not making a generic statement about somebody, you are referring explicitly to kitty.

Comment: Thank you so much for this informative answer. So based on your comments: I would do the following? ¬(Accident(thabo) ∨ Accident(kitty) ∨ Accident(betty). Regarding the use of ∀x and ∃ x then it is to say that only when the statement is generic such as Some people driving lorries in Durban obey the traffic rules. ∃x[(Drives(x, durban) ⇒ Obeys(x))]? Then re Kitty is involved in an accident only if she does not obey the traffic rules would it be correct to then say (¬ (Obeys(kitty)  ⇒ accident(kitty))?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. Although in your first example don't forget the closing bracket. * Accident(betty)) :)

Comment: Neither Kitty nor Betty obeys the traffic rules.

∀x [¬(obeys(kitty) ∨ obeys(betty))]

Can you spot the error here?

Comment: ∀x is a universal quantifier which does not need to be used here as the statement is not generic. i.e. the objects are defined and x is not being used in the formula either so this would no be correct?

Comment: Using a more generic question: Some people driving lorries in Durban obey the traffic rules. Would it be correct to write this as follows? ∃x∃y Drives(x,y) ∧ Obeys(x). I just want to be sure I have the right idea here. :)

Comment: To your first question, correct. You do not need a universal quantifier.

Comment: Regarding your second question, what you wrote reads "There is a person x such that there is a person y such that x drives y and y obeys the rules. Because the object of drive doesn't change (Ie: it's always a lorry) you could just decide that D(x) = "x drivers a lorry" or, if you wanted to, you could also write D(x, lorry) but, being lorry a constant, I'd go for the first version. So, something like  ∃x Drives(x) ∧ Obeys(x) would be more appropriate. The only time you have to use quantifiers is if you are referring to a generic subject, (1/2)

Comment: then the sentence is usually introduced by "All people" or "Some people" (2/2)

Comment: Unless Betty obeys the traffic rules when she drives a lorry in Bloemfontein, she is involved in an accident.

∀x [(obeys(betty) ∧ ∀y(Drives(betty, bloemfontein)) ⇒ accident(betty)]

This is wrong too. Firstly, you use two universal quantifiers whose variable is never seen again. Further, what you are saying is that if betty drives in bloemf. obeying the laws she will have an accident. I suggest relooking :)

Comment: Thanks. So re Unless Betty then would it not be better to negate obeys(betty) and drop the quantifiers. So ¬(obeys(betty)) ∧ (Drives(betty, bloemfontein)) ⇒ accident(betty).

Comment: One more using quantifiers to see if this has hit home. Somebody driving a lorry in Bloemfontein does not obey the traffic rules but is not involved in an accident. ∃x Drives(x,bloemfontein) ∧ ¬( Obeys(x)) ⇒ ¬(Accident(x))

Comment: Yes, that works. Except, and somebody more experienced then me may clarify on this, I see a possible ambiguity in the statement. It could be read as [¬(obeys(betty)) ∧ (Drives(betty, bloemfontein))] ⇒ accident(betty) or  ¬(obeys(betty)) ∧ [(Drives(betty, bloemfontein)) ⇒ accident(betty)]. I may be wrong, but I'd evising making it explicit by adding brackets.

Comment: @TahliaElcome no, hint, you do not need an implication. It's just three statements so just use 'ands'

Comment: I must thank you! You've been incredibly helpful and should be commended for your insight and overall willingness to help!

Comment: @TahliaElcome no problem! Sorry for the delayed reply, timezone difference meant at some point I just drifted into sleep. If you need any more help feel free to get in touch! :)